# How to fix Xcode source control inline comparison tool?

Tags: xcode, version-control, editor

On Xcode Version 13.4.1, ran on MacOS Monterey 12.5, showing single line inline comparison leads to displaying glitched, but selectable, line of text.
Multiple line comparison shows all but last line normally. The last one is glitched too.

Is there any way to restore xcode to its default state to make this tool useable again?

Examples:

Single line glitched inline comparison

[image: 1]

Multiline glitched comparison

[image: 2]